# sort a file based on user input

Tags: c++, sorting, file-read

I am trying to sort a file based on the users choice of 2 files. I'm using a string variable and passing it into the `instream()` but it keeps going into the `if` statement that says the file is corrupt or does not exist. I know it exists because when I hardcode the file name in then it works perfectly fine! I'm sure its something simple but I just can't figure it out. I'm very new to c++ so please be thorough with your answers so that I can understand and learn. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

std::string file = "";
std::ofstream out("outputfile.txt");
std::vector<int> numbers;
std::string sortType = "";

void sort(std::vector<int>);
void MergeSort(vector<int> &numbers);


int main()
{
  std::cout << "Which type of sort would you like to perform(sort or mergesort)?\n";
  std::cin >> sortType;

  std::cout << "Which file would you like to sort?\n";
  std::cin >> file;

  std::ifstream in(file);
  //Check if file exists
  if(!in)
  {
    std::cout << std::endl << "The File is corrupt or does not exist! ";
    return 1;
  }

  // Read all the ints from in:
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(in), std::istream_iterator<int>(),
            std::back_inserter(numbers));

  //check if the file has values
  if(numbers.empty())
  {
      std::cout << std::endl << "The file provided is empty!";
      return 1;
  } else
  {
      if(sortType == "sort")
      {
          sort(numbers);
      }else
      {
          MergeSort(numbers);
      }

      // Print the vector with tab separators:
      std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),
                std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t"));
      std::cout << std::endl;

        // Write the vector to a text file
      std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),
                std::ostream_iterator<int>(out, "\t"));
        std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

void sort(std::vector<int>)
{
  // Sort the vector:
  std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
  std::unique(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

  return;
}

vector<int> Merge(vector<int> &left, vector<int> &right)
{
    std::vector<int> result;

    while (left.size() > 0 && right.size() > 0)
    {
        if (left[0] <= right[0])
        {
            result.push_back(left[0]);
            left.erase(left.begin());
        } else
        {
            result.push_back(right[0]);
            right.erase(right.begin());
        }
    }

    if (left.size() > 0)
    {
        result.insert(result.end(), left.begin(), left.end());
    } else
    {
        result.insert(result.end(), right.begin(), right.end());
    }
    return result;
}

void MergeSort(vector<int> &numbers)
{
    if (numbers.size() <= 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    // split vector into two peices
    vector<int> left, right;
    unsigned int Middle = numbers.size() / 2;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Middle; i++)
    {
        left.push_back(numbers[i]);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = Middle; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        right.push_back(numbers[i]);
    }

    MergeSort(left);
    MergeSort(right);
    numbers = Merge(left, right);
    return;
}
```

Comment: I am now getting `error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(std::string&)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still checking the file given by the name `""`. When you put the line

```
std::ifstream in(file);
```

it opens the stream to the file specified by the name "" (the value of `file` at that point). Later, you say

```
if (!in)
```

without actually updating the file used.

Try this:

```
std::ifstream in; //no file specified

//the following comes before if (!in)
in.open (file);
```

This will open the stream to the inputted value of `file`.

A better way to do this would be to just declare and open the file in place of the second line and lose the first:

```
std::ifstream in (file); //after they input the filename
```

Using global variables is a generally bad idea if you don't have any reason to. It's better to pass them around in functions, or contain it all in a class.

Also, I notice you've declared `using namespace std;`, but still use `std::vector` etc. I would definitely opt for the latter and remove the former. Take care to add the resolution to the couple of things there missing it then though.

Comment: That makes sense. Now im getting an error on that line where I open the file using both ways you suggested. 
`error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(std::string&)' `
I only made the changes you suggested. Besides that its exactly the same as above.

Comment: @Fourthmeal70, could you update your code to reflect the changes? That seems odd.

Comment: Code is updated. Nothing changed besides moving the `std::ifstream in(file)` to right before the `if(!in)` statement.

Comment: @Fourthmeal70, I keep forgetting this, but the parameter is of type `const char *`, not `std::string`. Use `file.c_str()` to get that. I'm not exactly sure how it was accepting the empty string before though.

Comment: That fixed it. So the `.c_str` basically converts a string into an object for `ifstream` to read? So why does it take a string just fine when I hardcode a file name in, for example: `ifstream in("test.txt")` Just curious and trying to understand completely how this works.

Comment: @Fourthmeal70, `c_str()` retrieves the internal `char *` that `std::string` has and appends a `'\0'` to it so that it is the C-style string representation. The `ifstream` parameter's type is the C-string type `const char *`, so you can pass it in. When you put a direct literal in, it's of type `const char[]`, which **decays** into `const char *`. These semantics were all present in C (minus the whole `ifstream` and `std::string`). In C++, we just have to deal with the compatibility. The tools are there to use if we need an `std::string` from a `char *` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `open()` the file before you check the status.